# Use gpg to pass the passphrase file to decrypt the files

Tags: vb.net, gnupg

I need use shell to pass the passphrase from a file, and want the comment line can read the passphrase from this file, --passphrase-fd is not working for me. It's always output an error "can not find the file". I debug the output and input files, and they are correct. Is might be the passphrase.cat file, but I checked, there is no problem in the file. Any problem in the comment line??

my code as follows and thanks for any help:

```
                        Shell(pgp & "--passphrase -fd 0 <C:\Temp\test.txt" & " -output " & output & "--decrypt " & input & """", AppWinStyle.Hide, True) ' the error happens here.


                    End If

'''  The error as follows: 
 ''' Unable to complete the request: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File not found. at Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell(String PathName, AppWinStyle Style, Boolean Wait, Int32 Timeout) at the Sign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\sign\MainForm.vb:line361
```

Comment: What's the exact command line executed (with other words, what is the string paramter for `Shell(...)`), and what's the exact and complete error message you receive? Have you verified the file was actually written?

Comment: @JensErat Hi, the string I passed in the command are "C:\Temp\test.cat" , output and input. The output == (txtRequestDestination.Text & foundFileInfo.Name).Remove((txtRequestDestination.Text ). Input=txtRequestSource.Text & foundFileInfo.Name . The error said "can not find the file".

Comment: @JensErat I tested these three parameters, but all the files existed. "Shell(pgp & "--passphrase -fd 0 <C:\Temp\test.cat" & " -output " & output & "--decrypt " & input & """", AppWinStyle.Hide, True) ' the error happens here."

Comment: Please provide the whole result of the string concatenation, for example by printing it through `Console.WriteLine` or similar functions. Also -- what happens if you execute that command on the command line?

Comment: @JensErat Hi I update the errors and edit my question. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured it out. Have to use -passphrase-file passwordfile.txt to decrypted my file in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I expect a whole bunch of issues. For further debugging, print the command to the command line instead of executing it with `Shell(...)`.

- I guess the `pgp` variable does not end with a space, thus the application tries to execute something like `C:\path\to\gnupg\gpg.exe--passphrase` instead of `C:\path\to\gnupg\gpg.exe` with `--passphrase` parameter
- The same issue likely exists between the `output` variable and the `--decrypt` command
- There may not be a space inside `--passphrase-fd`, you wrote `passphrase -fd`
- `--output` is a long parameter and requires two dashes (you wrote `-output`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I run this comment line in the CMD.exe: C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG> gpg2.exe --passphrase-fd 0 < c:\Temp\test.txt -d -o "c:\Request\123.txt" "d:\123.txt.pgp"  this comment line is working

Comment: But if I use this in my VB.net is not working. Shell(pgp & " --passphrase-fd 0 < C:\Temp\test.txt -d -o " & Chr(34) & (txtRequestDestination.Text & foundFileInfo.Name).Remove((txtRequestDestination.Text & foundFileInfo.Name).Length - 4, 4) & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & txtRequestSource.Text & foundFileInfo.Name & Chr(34)). Is any code problem here?  and pgp = "C:\Program Files\GNU\GnuPG\gpg2.exe "

Comment: Again, please provide the exact string resulting from all those concatenations. With other words: the exact string without any variables and concatenations that is finally executed by `Shell(...)`. Everything else is guesswork and just results in endless discussions.